# Can I disable banded rows by default for new tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

When inserting a table into a worksheet, the Banded Rows table style option is enabled by default. I'm looking to disable this, I find fill colors to be very distracting.

Is there a way to toggle this setting by default? I'd like it to work across all worksheets, and across all themes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new workbook.
2. Create a sample table there.
3. Switch to the *Design* tab, choose a non-banded table style, right click on it and select "*Set as Default*" from the context menu.
4. Delete your table.
5. Save your workbook as default workbook template:

   - "File name": book
   - "Save as type": Excel template.
   - The path is C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\

   (this folder may be hidden by default).
6. Restart Excel.

Hope that helps.

You can read more about default workbook templates in [Customize how Excel starts](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Customize-how-Excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19).

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't do anything. I tried both the path you're mentioning, and the XLStart folder in the application folder. Can this be done in Excel 2013 under Windows 7?

Comment: I have the same configuration (Win 7 + Excel 2013). I have followed the steps again and set another table as the Default one. It worked. 
Please make sure the file name is book.xltx and that you restart Excel. Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: Your steps are very clear and I followed them to the dot, but it doesn't change anything. It has to have something to do with user restrictions on my device, I'll have to ask our service desk.

Comment: I think you need to do it in `Personal.xlsb` - which sets the defaults for other spreadsheets - like how `Normal.dot` is in MS Word.